# Write Unit test for [frombody] data binding returns null C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, data-binding

I would like to write a unit test for `[frombody]` data binding that returns `null` in C#.

So I've got this model:

```
 public class Model
    {
        public int number{ get; set; }
    }
```

And that is the Action for the web service:

```
  [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult API([FromBody]Model model)
   {     
      if (model== null)
      {
        return Json(new { error = "Could not decode request: JSON parsing failed" });
       }
     //some logic to get responsesToReturn;
     return Json(responsesToReturn);
   }
```

So I used the built-in data-binding to check the validity of the passed-in data.Say if the client send a `Json` number : "abc", the model object will become null after the data-binding. (Because "abc" is not convertible to int)

So I would like to write a Unit test for this behaviour.Here is my current test:

```
 [TestClass]
public class ModelControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAPIModelIsNull()
    {
        var controller = new ModelController();
        Model model = null;
        var result = controller.API(model);
        object obj = new { error = "Could not decode request: JSON parsing failed" };
        var expectedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedJson, result);
    }
}
```

I kept getting this `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. I am guessing because I explicitly set the model to `null`, but the action expect a instance of the `Model`. But in the application, the data-binding does return `null` when the request data in invalid.
So the question is how do I write a unit test for `[frombody]` data-binding return `null`?

Comment: The test looks correct. what line do you get the `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on?

Comment: Why would you write such a test? If the model binder gives you an empty object, then it will never be null and your if condition in the controller method will never be satisfied, hence no point in having that if condition or writing a test for it?

Comment: @ zaitsman this one. `Model model = null; var result = controller.API(model)`. Seems like I cannot set the model to null. But in the Action, the data-binder does return a null model to me when invalid data is passed-in and that is where the `if (model== null)` condition met.

Comment: @Vidmantas Blazevicius actually the `if (model== null)` in my controller action does fire when the passed in data is invalid, and I would like to test it in my unit test...But the system does not allow me to explicitly set a model object to `null` though..

Answer (score 4):

I found out the reason. It was not because that I cannot assign an object to `null`. It was because that when I ran the test, the `Response.StatusCode = 400` in the controller give me the `System.NullReferenceException` Because the `Reponse` in the test controller is `null`.

So I just set the `Response` in my test controller like so:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestAPIShowInfoIsNull()
    {
        //arrange
        var controller = new ShowsInfoController();
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();
        controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
        var response = controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response;
        //act
        ShowsInfo showsInfo = null;
        var result = controller.API(showsInfo);
        //assert

        Assert.AreEqual(400, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(JsonResult));
    }
```

Comment: what is `ShowsInfo ` as `API` takes `Model`